# MongoDB Group aggregation multiple field can push specific array field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

my mongodb document below

```
{
    "seq": 1,
    "cut": [
        {
            "script":[
                {
                    "type": "a",
                    "text": "a1"
                },
                {
                    "type": "a",
                    "text": "a2"
                },
                {
                    "type": "b",
                    "text": "b1"
                },
                {
                    "type": "c",
                    "text": "c1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "script":[
                {
                    "type": "d",
                    "text": "d1"
                },
                {
                    "type": "a",
                    "text": "a3"
                },
                {
                    "type": "c",
                    "text": "c2"
                },
                {
                    "type": "b",
                    "text": "b2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i want document aggregation with **type** key using `$unwind` and `$group` like below.

```
{
    "seq": 1,
    "a": ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
    "b": ["b1", "b2"],
    "c": ["c1", "c2"],
    "d": ["d1"]
}
```

first, use `$unwind` aggregation.

```
$unwind: {
    path: "$cut",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
}
```

and, it first aggregaion pipeline result is:

```
{
    "seq": 1,
    "cut": {
        "script":[
            {
                "type": "a",
                "text": "a1"
            },
            {
                "type": "a",
                "text": "a2"
            },
            {
                "type": "b",
                "text": "b1"
            },
            {
                "type": "c",
                "text": "c1"
            }
        ]
        
    }
}

{
    "seq": 1,
    "cut": {
        "script":[
            {
                "type": "d",
                "text": "d1"
            },
            {
                "type": "a",
                "text": "a3"
            },
            {
                "type": "c",
                "text": "c2"
            },
            {
                "type": "b",
                "text": "b2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

next, unwind **cut.script**.

```
$unwind: {
  path: "$cut.script",
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
}
```

its result is:

```
{
    "seq": 1,
    "cut": {
        "script":{
            "type": "a",
            "text": "a1"
        }
    }
}

{
    "seq": 1,
    "cut": {
        "script":{
            "type": "a",
            "text": "a2"
        }
    }
}

and more 6 document..
```

and last, i want this results grouping with **seq** field. so i use `$push` expression.

```
{
    _id: "$seq",
    "a": {
        $push: "$cut.script.text"
    },
    "b": {
        $push: "$cut.script.text"
    },
    "c": {
        $push: "$cut.script.text"
    },
    "d": {
        $push: "$cut.script.text"
    }
}
```

but it `$push` expression is push all item of script.
how can `$push` use condition pushes specific field (ex; "text" value with "type" equal to "a") value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this using $cond in aggregation

```
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$seq",
          "a": {
            $push: {
              $cond: { 
                if: { $eq: [ "$cut.script.type", "a" ] }, 
                then: ["$cut.script.text"] ,
                else: null,
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: i tried this, 'null' element pushed in array. can be remove 'null' element?

Comment: maybe '$$REMOVE' can help this...

Comment: Yes you can try with $$REMOVE as well

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer a more dynamic/generic solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$cut" },
   { $unwind: "$cut.script" },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { seq: "$seq", type: "$cut.script.type" },
         text: { $push: "$cut.script.text" }
      }
   },
   { $sort: { "_id.type": 1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$_id.seq",
         data: { $push: { k: "$_id.type", v: "$text" } }
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: { $mergeObjects: [{ seq: "$_id" }, { $arrayToObject: "$data" }] } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JtrNFS2jupc)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([Mongoplayground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4HvIAQahsGJ)):

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $unwind: {
    path: "$cut",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
  }
},
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$cut.script"
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    "_id": "$seq",
    "a": {
      $push: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$cut.script.type",
              "a"
            ]
          },
          then: "$cut.script.text",
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    },
    "b": {
      $push: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$cut.script.type",
              "b"
            ]
          },
          then: "$cut.script.text",
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    },
    "c": {
      $push: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$cut.script.type",
              "c"
            ]
          },
          then: "$cut.script.text",
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    },
    "d": {
      $push: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$cut.script.type",
              "d"
            ]
          },
          then: "$cut.script.text",
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: very helpful thanks!!